# Post list of accounts to delete, confirm the delete and then delete the data PHP, Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

Step 1

I have a form with a list of accounts, these accounts have checkboxes which allow the user to select multiple accounts to delete them.

Step 2

The user clicks on some checkboxes and then clicks the delete button, This then brings up a Jquery UI dialog box to ask the user to confirm the deleting of the data.

Step 3

The post data then gets sent to a PHP script which is then processed, resulting in the correct data being deleted.

The problem is that the data posted in Step 2 is the account ID which the PHP script need in order to delete the accounts, This is then lost when the user clicks to confirm to delete the data. I want a confirm dialog but dont know how to pass the post data agian to the PHP script.

I'm guessing its something to do with passing the data in the Jquery dialog form but im not sure how to go about doing that.

This is the Jquery UI dialog code used to confirm the delete.

```
   <script type="javascript">
    $(function() {
            // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system    (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
            $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

            $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height:200,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Confirm: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                        location.replace("<?php  echo   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?delete=yes"; ?>"); 

                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        location.replace("<?php  echo  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?delete=no"; ?>");

                    }

                }
            });
        });
</script>

    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
    <p>Are you sure you wanted to delete the selected accounts? and their related data?</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Account History</li>
            <li>PPC</li>
            <li>FTP</li>
            <li>Phone Number</li>
            <li>Phone Number Stats</li>
        </ul>

  </div>
```

The post form is fine, its just the dialog thats the problem and how to get the data across agian to the PHP script.

Comment: where is you code for us to check where your going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could just do the following:

1: create a JS function (that can be used on all your forms) and include it where needed.

```
  function confirmation(question)
  {
     return confirm(question + " (OK = Yes   Cancel = No)");
  }
```

2: place an onSubmit on the form in question

```
  onSubmit="return confirmation('Do you really want to delete?');"
```

This will then return true if the user clicks Ok and the form is submitted. If the user clicks Cancel then false is returned and the form does not submit.